# How to push multiple view controllers onto navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Newbie here programming my first app (having made several tutorial apps). I am using a view controller called 'RootViewController' as a navigation controller. I have successfully pushed another view controller on top of this called 'ClientListViewController' using the command:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:clientListViewController animated:YES];
```

I am now in the ClientListViewController and trying to push another view controller onto the stack called 'AddClientViewController'. I would like to make this a modal view controller in the form of a UIModalPresentationFormSheet. I am trying to use a variation of the command above to push the new view controller but i don't know how to replace the 'self'. I have tried:

```
[RootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:AddClientViewController animated:YES];
```

and...

```
[[RootViewController navigationController] pushViewController:AddClientViewController animated:YES];
```

as well as each of these combinations using small 'R's for the word Root. Still no luck.

For clarity, I have used the following code at the top of my implementation file.

```
#import "AddClientViewController.h"
```

Am I approaching this in the right way, or should I be using a brand new navigation controller to add it to?

Any pointers greatly received.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `UIViewController` has a property named `navigationController`.  This property refers to the nearest enclosing `UINavigationController`, if there is one.  So you can just say `self.navigationController` in your `ClientListViewController`.

In iOS, we normally capitalize class names.  So it sounds like `AddClientViewController` is a class name.  You need to have an instance of that class to push it on the navigation controller's stack.  Something like this:

```
AddClientViewController *addClientVC = [[AddClientViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:addClientViewController animated:YES];
```

You might need to use a different init method or set some properties of `addClientVC` before pushing it; that depends on your implementation of `AddClientViewController`.

If you want to present it modally, you don't push it on the navigation controller's stack.  Instead you do it this way:

```
AddClientViewController *addClientVC = [[AddClientViewController alloc] init];
addClientVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:addClientVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```