# How to link one button to two Views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a req for a button which when clicked has two options:1)Go to View a1 and 2) Go to view a2.

Is it possible to do that?

I have a button "Btn" in First Screen "A" and that button is linked to two views. 
My doubt is that

"How does it know which view to present on button click?(whatever the case whether it is one after the other or anything else)"

Comment: share your code please.

Comment: It is my requirement, i am new to iOS actually. I didn't write any code for that still. I searched in google and read some tutorials but didn't find any solution for that. Is it possible to do that?How can one button handles two events?please help me

Comment: @venu.ezgiri read some basic about objective-c

Comment: You should check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619147/problem-pushing-multiple-view-controllers-onto-navigation-controller-stack).

Comment: Even [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150472/how-to-push-multiple-view-controllers-onto-navigation-controller) may get you something

Comment: Same doubt araised for me too. But they said that it uses stack concept. i am really worried about that.help me.

Comment: @venu.ezgiri you need to give more explanation. what must be done exactly? open two views in the same time or in turn?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I think it involves stack concept. Do you know any tuto that explains best about Stacks?and also i need to know which is high priority whether Nav controller or tabbar controller, why?

Answer (score 1):

Well, i hope i understand you and i hope you yourself understand what you need. Since opening two view controllers simultaneously seems absurd to me i assume you need to open the view controllers in turn. It can be done like this:

```
static BOOL shouldOpenFirst = YES;

- (void)handleButtonClik:(id)sender
{
   UIViewController *viewController = shouldOpenFirst ? [FirstViewController new] : [SecondViewController new];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController];

 shouldOpenFirst = !shouldOpenFirst;

}
```